# Double GET method Router Issue

Tags: php

```
if($_GET){
    $way = 'theme/page/';
    $extension = '.php';
    $content = $yol . strip_tags(trim($_GET['sayfa'])) . $uzanti;
    require_once "$content";
    }

if($_GET){
        $way = 'tema/information/';
        $extension = '.php';
        $content = $yol . strip_tags(trim($_GET['information'])) . $uzanti;
        require_once "$content";
        }
```

i have two different form with GET method. How can i check both on one page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

Added isset($_GET['sayfa']) and isset($_GET['information']) for the individual conditions.

```
     if(isset($_GET['sayfa'])){
        $way = 'theme/page/';
        $extension = '.php';
        $content = $yol . strip_tags(trim($_GET['sayfa'])) . $uzanti;
        require_once "$content";
     }

    if(isset($_GET['information'])){
            $way = 'tema/information/';
            $extension = '.php';
            $content = $yol . strip_tags(trim($_GET['information'])) . $uzanti;
            require_once "$content";
     }
```

Comment: aa :D i tried it but i forget to type isset xD thank you very much